# JavaScript objects in Java?

Tags: java

How do I loop over a string of item and create an object based on that?

I currently have this code:

```
public static Object ParseParams(String string)
{
    Object params = new Object();
    String[] lines = string.split("\n");
    for(String line : lines)
    {
        String[] splittedLine = line.split("=");
        params[splittedLine[0]] = splittedLine[1]; //JavaScript syntax, not Java!
    }
    return params;
}
```

The input string is in this format:

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
foo=bar
```

How do I fix the problematic line?

**Edit**

Sometimes the string would look like this:

```
foo=bar
param=1=hello
param=2=world
```

Would it be possible with Maps in Java to get the output like this:

```
foo
  bar
param
  1
    hello
  2
    world
```

So the Maps are sometimes nested, and it you would retrieve `hello` by calling `params.get("param").get("1");`

Comment: Oh, that's not how objects in Java work at *all*. You may want to stick with a `Map` implementation like `HashMap`, or use a JSON library if that's your end goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want either a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), or a JSON library.

### Maps

```
public static Map<String, String> ParseParams(String string)
{
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] lines = string.split("\n");
    for(String line : lines)
    {
        String[] splittedLine = line.split("=");
        params.put(splittedLine[0], splittedLine[1]);
    }
    return params; // Get a param with params.get(key);
}
```

In general you'll want a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (fast but not stored in order), but there's also a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which is slightly slower but stored in order (which can be useful sometimes).

### JSON

The format JavaScript uses for objects is used as a general-purpose storage format called JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). This is **only** useful for storage / printing / network transmission. Internally, Java JSON libraries use maps (JavaScript interpreters probably do too).

There are several Java APIs, but [StackOverflow users seem to recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) [Json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html):

```
public static JSONObject ParseParams(String string)
{
    // Note that we need everything from the other method anyway
    return JSONObject.fromObject(ParseParams(string));
}
```

EDIT:

You're already reaching the point where using a `Map` is strained. I'd suggest just using a class:

```
class MyStuff {
    String foo;
    Map<String, String> params;
}
```

It *is* possible to nest Maps, like `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` or `Map<String, Object>`, but you really should be using classes for this.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please take a look at my edit of the question?

Comment: <noobQuestion>How would you do that with classes?</noobQuestion>

Comment: @Tylio - Sorry, I don't think I could give a decent introduction to classes. You could try the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).